# Why does a Redux reducer have to be side-effect free?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have been using Redux in my React app and something has been bothering me. The documentation for Redux makes it very clear that the reducer should be state free. You often see examples like this:

```
function reducer(state = { exampleState: true }, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
  case "ACTION_EXAMPLE":
    return Object.assign({}, state, { exampleState: false });
  default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

My question is why is this required at all? JavaScript is single threaded. There is no chance of a race condition inside the reducer. As far as I can tell, a Redux store is only capable of returning the current state of the store, so it seems weird that there is so much focus on pure functions.

Comment: Excuse me, what does "there is no chance of a race condition inside reducer" mean ?

Comment: https://goshakkk.name/redux-side-effect-approaches/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The case for pure functions is made in the author's [documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/PriorArt.html). Sure, you can write reducers with impure functions, but:

> Development features like time travel, record/replay, or hot reloading will break.

If none of those features provide a benefit or are of interest you, then, by all means, write impure functions. However, the question then would become, why use Redux?

Comment: Thanks Brett, I wasn't aware of those features.

Answer (score 2):

Just because it's single threaded doesn't mean it's not asynchronous, but that's beside the point really. Side effects have nothing to do with threading and everything to do with making sure your object behaves the way its API says it will: If it had state, you could have different behaviour depending on how many calls were made to it, and what data was passed for each call, instead of being an object with constant behaviour regardless of when you call it.

The important part is the "always behave exactly the same way for exactly the same input". Adding and using state is almost literally a promise that this will not be the case.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't answer question. All of those things are possible modifying the state directory. Consider a reducer that does this: `(state, action) => { state.prop += 1; return state; }`. This is not side-effect free but it will have different behavior depending on how many calls were made.

Comment: You just literally described an unpredictable side-effect. You've just updated an object that the store does not own: what just happened to the owner of the object? It's `prop` value magically changed, what are the consequences of that? Why would you even think you know if other objects might also do that, including code you don't even know anything about (modules etc)? Don't write code with side-effects, because at best you, but at worst everyone using your code, won't understand the repercussions of them, and won't be able to rely on code behaving deterministically predictable

Comment: @Max "it will have different behavior depending on how many calls were made" If every single call that was made, with the same input changes the state in the same predictable and reproducible way, it does not have side effects. EDIT: also, you are never supposed to operate on the state object itself. That's a no no

Comment: @MitchKarajohn my question is asking why is operating on the instance itself a no-no? I understand what side-effect free is, but I don't understand why the reducers must be side effect free.

Comment: @Mike If the store doesn't own the state, then who owns it?

Comment: @Max "why is operating on the instance itself a no-no" Because Redux, among other things, is supposed to make it easy for you to keep a history of actions for debugging purposes and not only. If you operate directly on the state object you can no longer do that, so you may as well use vanilla flux

Answer (score 1):

Because

> [Redux is a **predictable** state container for JavaScript apps.](https://github.com/reactjs/redux#redux)

Emphasis on 'predictable'.

Adding side effects makes it **un**predictable

Comment: Can you add some justification on how on behavior could become unpredictable?

Comment: Ok. Let's say that, for whatever reason, you add an XHRequest in your reducer, that on success, makes changes on the `state`. You just made your reducer unpredictable, because now you cannot guarantee that everytime your reducer is executed with the same exact input it will always change the state in the same predictable way. (Because what if the XHRequest fails?)

Comment: Sure, you wouldn't want to do make an AJAX call in a reducer. But that doesn't mean that the reducer **must** be side-effect free. Your example shows that the reducer should be deterministic.